# Estimate formants using LPC in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I'm new to signal processing (and numpy, scipy, and matlab for that matter). I'm trying to estimate vowel formants with LPC in Python by adapting this matlab code:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/formant-estimation-with-lpc-coefficients.html

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import numpy
import wave
import math
from scipy.signal import lfilter, hamming
from scikits.talkbox import lpc

"""
Estimate formants using LPC.
"""

def get_formants(file_path):

    # Read from file.
    spf = wave.open(file_path, 'r') # http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/people/hayes/103/Charts/VChart/ae.wav

    # Get file as numpy array.
    x = spf.readframes(-1)
    x = numpy.fromstring(x, 'Int16')

    # Get Hamming window.
    N = len(x)
    w = numpy.hamming(N)

    # Apply window and high pass filter.
    x1 = x * w
    x1 = lfilter([1., -0.63], 1, x1)

    # Get LPC.
    A, e, k = lpc(x1, 8)

    # Get roots.
    rts = numpy.roots(A)
    rts = [r for r in rts if numpy.imag(r) >= 0]

    # Get angles.
    angz = numpy.arctan2(numpy.imag(rts), numpy.real(rts))

    # Get frequencies.
    Fs = spf.getframerate()
    frqs = sorted(angz * (Fs / (2 * math.pi)))

    return frqs

print get_formants(sys.argv[1])
```

Using [this file](http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/people/hayes/103/Charts/VChart/ae.wav) as input, my script returns this list:

```
[682.18960189917243, 1886.3054773107765, 3518.8326108511073, 6524.8112723782951]
```

I didn't even get to the last steps where they filter the frequencies by bandwidth because the frequencies in the list aren't right. According to Praat, I should get something like this (this is the formant listing for the middle of the vowel):

```
Time_s     F1_Hz        F2_Hz         F3_Hz         F4_Hz
0.164969   731.914588   1737.980346   2115.510104   3191.775838
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much

### UPDATE:

I changed this

`x1 = lfilter([1., -0.63], 1, x1)`

to

`x1 = lfilter([1], [1., 0.63], x1)`

as per Warren Weckesser's suggestion and am now getting

`[631.44354635609318, 1815.8629524985781, 3421.8288991389031, 6667.5030877036006]`

I feel like I'm missing something since F3 is very off.

### UPDATE 2:

I realized that the `order` being passed to `scikits.talkbox.lpc` was off due to a difference in sampling frequency. Changed it to:

```
Fs = spf.getframerate()
ncoeff = 2 + Fs / 1000
A, e, k = lpc(x1, ncoeff)
```

Now I'm getting:

`[257.86573127888488, 774.59006835496086, 1769.4624576002402, 2386.7093679399809, 3282.387975973973, 4413.0428174593926, 6060.8150432549655, 6503.3090645887842, 7266.5069407315023]`

Much closer to Praat's estimation!

Comment: Can you compute/show the spectrogram from the UCLA signal? In the MATLAB example there are two vowels (voice saying "MATLAB") and you can clearly see them in the time frequency plot. They analyze between 0.1 and 0.25 seconds in the MATLAB example.  Without knowing what the content of the UCLA signal is its hard to give advice on what segment to analyze. But I suspect you want to analyze a subset that contains one vowel at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem had to do with the order being passed to the lpc function. `2 + fs / 1000` where `fs` is the sampling frequency is the rule of thumb according to:

http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/courses/spsci/matlab/lect10.html

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to get the results you expect, but I do notice two things which might cause some differences:

1. Your code uses `[1, -0.63]` where the MATLAB code from the link you provided has `[1 0.63]`.
2. Your processing is being applied to the entire `x` vector at once instead of smaller segments of it (see where the MATLAB code does this: `x = mtlb(I0:Iend);` ).

---

Hope that helps.

Comment: 1) I got the pre-emphasis filter code from here:
http://pydoc.net/Python/scikits.talkbox/0.2.5/scikits.talkbox.features.mfcc/

I've tried with `[1., 0.63]` and `[1., -0.63]` and neither gave me the result I was hoping for.

2) I tried setting `x` to the middle third of the signal but it made very little difference in the frequencies returned.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems:

- According to the link, the "pre-emphasis filter is a highpass all-pole (AR(1)) filter".  The signs of the coefficients given there are correct: `[1, 0.63]`.  If you use `[1, -0.63]`, you get a lowpass filter.
- You have the first two arguments to [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) reversed.

So, try changing this:

```
x1 = lfilter([1., -0.63], 1, x1)
```

to this:

```
x1 = lfilter([1.], [1., 0.63], x1)
```

I haven't tried running your code yet, so I don't know if those are the only problems.

Comment: I changed that line to `x1 = lfilter([1], [1., 0.63], x1)` (first argument must be a array-like). That got me these results: `[631.44354635609318, 1815.8629524985781, 3421.8288991389031, 6667.5030877036006]`. I still feel like I'm missing something since that third formant is very off.

Comment: I fixed the missing brackets--thanks.  Are you sure that `lpc` from `scikits.talkbox` gives the same result as matlab's `lpc`?  Do you have matlab so you can compare the results?