# Linear Predictive Coding in Python

Tags: python

Are there any modules in python that does the Linear Predictive Coding? I have an audio signal on which I want to use the LPC to find out its features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scikits.talkbox seems to have lpc and mfcc. For audio processing, I usually use librosa, but this module does not have lpc.

https://github.com/cournape/talkbox/tree/master/scikits/talkbox/linpred

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107806/estimate-formants-using-lpc-in-python